# How do I simplify my code for creating boxes?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner who just started learning how to code in HTML5 two weeks ago. I want to create a grid with a bunch of boxes. There seems to be a way just by HTML, but I want to do try it in JavaScript. I set up a function for the boxes:

```
function outlineRect(leftX, topY, width, height, strokeColor, lineThickness) {
     canvasContext.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
     canvasContext.lineWidth = lineThickness;
     canvasContext.strokeRect(leftX, topY, width, height);
}
```

Then I started with the boxes. In the end, I want a four row, eight column grid. Here's what I have:

```
var boardBoxX = 375
var boardBoxY = 173
var boardBox = 75
var highlightBorder = 5
var blackBorder = 2

outlineRect(boardBoxX, boardBoxY, boardBox, boardBox, '#ffe9b5', highlightBorder);
outlineRect(boardBoxX, boardBoxY, boardBox, boardBox, '#000000', blackBorder);
outlineRect(boardBoxX+boardBox, boardBoxY, boardBox, boardBox, '#ffe9b5', highlightBorder);
outlineRect(boardBoxX+boardBox, boardBoxY, boardBox, boardBox, '#000000', blackBorder);
```

The idea is that I would add the box length (boardBox) to the X-coordinate (boardBoxX) until 8 boxes had been made. Then the y-coordinate (boardBoxY) would be added by the boardBox and the X-coordinate resets. I wanted to simplify the code because otherwise there would be 64 lines for just a table. The best I could muster was an animated box...
Can someone tell me how to simplify it? Many thanks to whoever replies to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step of simplifying:

I would start by making another function `doubleOutline`, to which you pass the X,Y,width,height but then it provides the colors and line thicknesses, and makes two calls to outlineRect -- that way for each "box" you can make a single function call, plus you don't have to repeat the colors & thicknesses every time.

Second step of simplifying:

I would then make some "for" loops that count through the X and Y positions of your box:

```
for (column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
  for (row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
    doubleOutline (boardBoxX + column*boardBox, boardBoxY + row*boardBox, boardBox, boardBox);
  }
}
```

So that counts through all your different row/column positions, and calculates the location to draw the next box, and because you have done step 1 and made a doubleOutline function that does simplifies your outlining sequence, you only need one call there.

There are other strategies possible for simplifying this, but this one hopefully helps!

Comment: I got it to work after a bit of tinkering. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! If you have time, click to "accept" my answer, I could use the rep ;-)